# iPad Mini suddenly denying my passcode

Tags: ipad

All the sudden my passcode doesn't unlock my iPad Mini. The iPad is not synced to any computer. How can I get back into my iPad without resetting it? What could have happened?

Comment: that doesn't sound good! I would recommend contacting apple support at https://getsupport.apple.com